# Прыгает напряжение GPU

Tags: gpu, видеокарта, msi

Прыгает напряжение GPU в msi afterburner и в GPU-Z. Это проблема с пк? Мсай я уже переустанавливал. При игре даже не в сильно требвательные игры как секиро.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это скрин с мсай, еще я заметил что это происходит во время переключения между окон. Так и должно быть, вчера просто так прыгало все когда все было закрыто.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не напряжение, а частота. Штатный режим работы.

Comment: Значит все норм? просто я обосрался когда в первый раз увидел.

Comment: В игре видеокарта работает, в других приложениях ее мощь не нужна. Так и работают процессоры - под нагрузкой напряжение и частота растет, без нагрузки падают чтобы не тратить зря электроэнергию и не греть воздух.

Comment: У меня прыгает частота когда переключаюсь между вкладками браузера и на сам браузер так еще и на максимум

Comment: Ностальгия, когда впервые купил игровую видеокарту)). Помню когда я купил впервые видеокарту GTX она грелась очень сильно и турбина капец как шумела. Я испугался и позвонил продавцу, он говорит, это нормально)).

Comment: @Павел 1660Super не нуждается в андервольтинге, она холодная, единственное что нужно сделать - это кулера настроить, что бы не пищала и не шумела зря.

Comment: @Евгений Ли Я не собирался ставить просто нормально что прыгает так сильно из-за браузера

Comment: @Павел наверное, главное пусть 30 минутный FurMark выдержит, а остальное всё ерунда)

Comment: Ок попробую, если что отпишу